# How to group and count elements of a JSON file with multiple objects on javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to javascript, and so far everything was fine until I ran into this dilemma, I need to restructure a JSON file as follows:

```
{
    firstName: "Joel",
    lastName: "Munz",
    total: 154,
    transaction: "111111",
    articles:[
        {
            sku: "abc123456",
            number: 2,
            price: 65
        },
        {
            sku: "def123456",
            number: 2,
            price: 24
        }
    ]
},
{
    firstName: "Patel",
    lastName: "Dass",
    total: 85,
    transaction: "222222",
    articles: [
        {
            sku: "abc123456",
            number: 1,
            price: 65
        },
        {
            sku: "def123456",
            number: 2,
            price: 10
        }
    ]
}
```

And my source file has the following structure:

```
{
    "transactions":[
        {
            "items":[
                {
                    "price":65,
                    "sku":"abc123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":65,
                    "sku":"abc123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":12,
                    "sku":"def123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":12,
                    "sku":"def123456"
                }
            ],
            "total":154,
            "transaction":"111111",
            "customer":{
                "firstName":"Joel",
                "lastName":"Munz"
            }
        },
        {
            "items":[
                {
                    "price":65,
                    "sku":"abc123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":10,
                    "sku":"ghi123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":10,
                    "sku":"ghi123456"
                }
            ],
            "total":85,
            "transaction":"222222",
            "customer":{
                "firstName":"Patel",
                "lastName":"Dass"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

what I have tried is the following, but it doesn't have the structure that I need. I've read about using the **reduce () forEach ()** function, but I don't know how to implement it to match the format I need.

```
const trans = data.transactions.map(transaction => ({
    "firstName": transaction.customer.firstName,
    "lastName": transaction.customer.lastName,
    "total":transaction.total,
    "order_id": transaction.transaction,  //OP
    "articles": {
        "sku":transaction.items.map(Item => Item.sku),
        "number":transaction.items.map(Item => Item.sku).length,
        "price":transaction.items.map(Item => Item.price)}
    }))
console.log(trans);
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're extremely close, it's just that instead of mapping each property of the `articles` property, you want to [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the entire `transaction.items` array, grouping the elements by `.sku` and then assigning the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of the resulting object to the `articles` property.

```
"articles": Object.values(
    transaction.items.reduce((a, Item) => {
      a[Item.sku] = a[Item.sku] || {
        "sku": Item.sku,
        "number": 0,
        "price": Item.price
      };
      a[Item.sku].number += 1;
      return a;
    }, {}))
```

instead of:

```
"articles": {
  "sku": transaction.items.map(Item => Item.sku),
  "number": transaction.items.map(Item => Item.sku).length,
  "price": transaction.items.map(Item => Item.price)}
```

```js
const data = { "transactions": [{ "items": [{ "price": 65, "sku": "abc123456" }, { "price": 65, "sku": "abc123456" }, { "price": 12, "sku": "def123456" }, { "price": 12, "sku": "def123456" }], "total": 154, "transaction": "111111", "customer": { "firstName": "Joel", "lastName": "Munz" } }, { "items": [{ "price": 65, "sku": "abc123456" }, { "price": 10, "sku": "ghi123456" }, { "price": 10, "sku": "ghi123456" }], "total": 85, "transaction": "222222", "customer": { "firstName": "Patel", "lastName": "Dass" } }] };

const trans = data.transactions.map(transaction => ({
  "firstName": transaction.customer.firstName,
  "lastName": transaction.customer.lastName,
  "total": transaction.total,
  "order_id": transaction.transaction,  //OP
  "articles": Object.values(
    transaction.items.reduce((a, Item) => {
      a[Item.sku] = a[Item.sku] || {
        "sku": Item.sku,
        "number": 0,
        "price": Item.price
      };
      a[Item.sku].number += 1;
      return a;
    }, {}))
}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(trans, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the articles should change to this:

```
"articles": transaction.items.map((Item, index) => ({
"sku": Item.sku,
"number": transaction.items.filter(item => item.sku ===Item.sku ).length, 
"price": Item.price
}))
```

the result would be the same as your example.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to start by creating a new 'class' with a constructor. This basically creates a template in the format you want this to be in ultimately. The 'constructor' parameters is where you will eventually enter the relevant data.

```
class customerProfile {
    constructor(firstName,lastName,total,transaction,articles) {
  this.firstName = firstName
  this.lastName = lastName
  this.total = total
  this.transaction = transaction
  this.articles = articles
  }
}
```

Once you have the constructor built you just need to use a for loop to iterate through the source, since the data you want is under 'transactions' stored as values of an array. Each time you iterate through a 'transaction' you will create a new customerProfile. The last step is to create an array (I called it 'profileArray') that you can store each new customerProfile in.

```
for(let i=0; i<source.transactions.length;i++){
    let firstName = source.transactions[i].customer.firstName
  let lastName = source.transactions[i].customer.lastName
  let total = source.transactions[i].total
  let transaction = source.transactions[i].transaction
  let articles = source.transactions[i].items
    profileArray[i] = new customerProfile(firstName,lastName,total,transaction,articles);
}
```

I don't know where you get the article 'number' from (not listed in the source), but I'm sure you can add that in easily if you understand this part. Here's a full example with a console.log so you can check.

```js
let source = {
    "transactions":[
        {
            "items":[
                {
                    "price":65,
                    "sku":"abc123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":65,
                    "sku":"abc123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":12,
                    "sku":"def123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":12,
                    "sku":"def123456"
                }
            ],
            "total":154,
            "transaction":"111111",
            "customer":{
                "firstName":"Joel",
                "lastName":"Munz"
            }
        },
        {
            "items":[
                {
                    "price":65,
                    "sku":"abc123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":10,
                    "sku":"ghi123456"
                },
                {
                    "price":10,
                    "sku":"ghi123456"
                }
            ],
            "total":85,
            "transaction":"222222",
            "customer":{
                "firstName":"Patel",
                "lastName":"Dass"
            }
        }
    ]
}

class customerProfile {
    constructor(firstName,lastName,total,transaction,articles) {
  this.firstName = firstName
  this.lastName = lastName
  this.total = total
  this.transaction = transaction
  this.articles = articles
  }
}

let profileArray = []

for(let i=0; i<source.transactions.length;i++){
    let firstName = source.transactions[i].customer.firstName
  let lastName = source.transactions[i].customer.lastName
  let total = source.transactions[i].total
  let transaction = source.transactions[i].transaction
  let articles = source.transactions[i].items
    profileArray[i] = new customerProfile(firstName,lastName,total,transaction,articles);
}

console.log(profileArray);
```